# Mini conda downloaded. Now how do I access it to write code?

Tags: miniconda

I downloaded mini conda. I'm very new to programming. How do I access the download to actually begin to write code? I've read to do it in the command prompt, but is there a seperate place to write the code, sort of how the r programming environment opens up a window for me to write in?

Answer (score 0):

Mini Conda is a [package manager](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) so it's just there to help you install/manage packages and setup your python environment. You can write your code in whatever editor you want such as vim, atom, or even text edit.